# Unable to use Datastore emulator with Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, datastore

I am trying to use datastore emulator with my nodejs application

Initially I have followed the instructions given in [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#windows)

Then in my node application :-

```js
var config = {
    projectId : "scio1-ts-datastore"
}

const datastore = require("@google-cloud/datastore")
const db = new datastore.Datastore(config)

const setdata = async () => {
    await db.save(({
        key : db.key('orders') , 
        data : {
            orderId : 1 , 
            orderType : "Hazardous"
        }
    }))
}

const getdata = async () => {
    const query = db.createQuery('orders')
    const [orders] = await db.runQuery(query)
    console.log(orders)

}

setdata()
getdata()
```

After this I had to run `gcloud auth application-default login` which I think is not needed to run as I am using datastore Emulator .

But even after this I am unable to run the app

Following error pops up :- [image]

Comment: I found that setting the `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` env var to `localhost:8081` after running `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` worked fine. However, as Petra Drevenšek points out, you need to run `gcloud auth application-default login` first, even though you're just using the local emulator (which is a bit weird).

Answer (score 1):

If your Node.js app does not read the environmental variable (per the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#windows) you used), you can initialize the datastore with endpoint explicitly given:

```
this.datastore = new Datastore({
    apiEndpoint: "0.0.0.0:8081"
});
```

Also make sure that you [authenticated with the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials#personal):

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This ensures that the `~/.config/gcloud` directory contains `application_default_credentials.json` which is needed to connect to a local Firestore emulator.

Edit: if you are running the app through webstorm or such, it's good to note that environmental variables are loaded when you start it. So if it's already running when you set the variables, restart it!